# How to use output cache programmatically for a particular user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to apply output cache programmatically to a particular control. But when I'm using this code, it stores all the page and other user control in cache output.

```
    if (Session["id"] != null)
    {            
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true); 
     }
```

Comment: Looks the same as this question: [Caching a user control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568837/caching-a-user-control-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`HttpResponse.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property gets caching policy (such as expiration time, privacy settings, and vary clauses) of a whole web page. That's why the code above caches the whole web page.

To cache your user control you could use [`PartialCachingAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz74we19.aspx). Is *says* that your control supports fragment caching. And then programmatically change the necessary caching properties through [`UserControl.CachePolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5z3ahdk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
[PartialCaching(0)]
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["id"] != null)
        {            
            this.CachePolicy.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional information could be found in the [Caching Portions of an ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx) articke on MSDN.

Comment: Alex is it cache store in clients side or server side. i want to store cache on client side.

Comment: @pargan, partial caching works only on the server side. Full caching can work either client and server side, or both.

Comment: Alex but i want to maintain cache on client side of a particular user control with programmatically. can u please suggest me . how can i do this. ?

Comment: @pargan, I'm afraid this is impossible